# VBA Getting data to a new worksheet for different format Excel

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, basic

I'm still new to VBA EXCEL programming.

I need to extract data from one sheet to another in a different format. However, many of the tutorial only seems to extract data rows by rows or range by range to a fresh sheet.

So this is my DataSheet1:

```
**School         Principal    Student    Student ID**
United College   Bill Gates   Peter      p3214
United College   Bill Gates   Mary       p4213
United College   Bill Gates   Forge      p7621
Beverly High     Melin Brad   Goge       p1111
Beverly High     Melin Brad   Fred       p2222
```

I want to make the data into a custom format in another datasheet. So here's my desired result:

```
School      United College
Principal   Bill Gates

Student   Student ID
Peter     p3214
Mary      p4213
Forge     p7621


School      Beverly High
Principal   Melinda Brad

Student   Student ID
Goge      p1111
Fred      p2222
```

Below are some of my codes to get from Sheet1 to Sheet2, but the code only shows to get the data from range to range. What are some of the concepts that should be used to extract the data into a custom format? My codes:

```
Dim secondsheet As Worksheet
Set secondsheet = workbook.Worksheets(2)
Dim firstsheet As Worksheet
Set firstsheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)

secondsheet.Range("A1", "C10").Value = firstsheet.Range("A1", "C10").Value
```

And the format that I intend to put my data in:

```
Range(<<call function for range>>).Select
With Selection
    .Value = "School"
    .Offset(1,0).Value = "Principal"
    .Offset(1,0).Font.Bold = True
    .Offset(4,1).Value = "Student"
    .Offset(4,1).Font.Bold = True
    .Offset(4,2).Value = "Student ID"
    .Offset(4,2).Font.Bold = True
```

So the answer I looking for is looping function since it's in this format. Any kind souls are willing to help me understand the concept for vba?

Answer (score 0):

Keep Data in Sheet1 and Run the macro... Small errors are there in my macro.. If u work it out can easily rectify

```
col1 = Sheet1.Cells(2, 1)
prin1 = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = "School"
Sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = "Principal"
Sheet2.Cells(2, 1) = col1
Sheet2.Cells(2, 2) = prin1
b = 5
c = 1
Sheet2.Cells(b - 1, 1) = "Student"
Sheet2.Cells(b - 1, 2) = "St ID"
a = 3

Do While Sheet1.Cells(a, 1) <> ""
If col1 = Sheet2.Cells(c + 1, 1) Then
Sheet2.Cells(b, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 3)
Sheet2.Cells(b, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 4)
b = b + 1
Else
c = b + 1
b = c + 3

col1 = Sheet1.Cells(a, 1)
prin1 = Sheet1.Cells(a, 2)
Sheet2.Cells(c, 1) = "School"
Sheet2.Cells(c, 2) = "Principal"
Sheet2.Cells(c + 1, 1) = col1
Sheet2.Cells(c + 1, 2) = prin1
Sheet2.Cells(b - 1, 1) = "Student"
Sheet2.Cells(b - 1, 2) = "St ID"
Sheet2.Cells(b, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 3)
Sheet2.Cells(b, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(a, 4)
End If
a = a + 1
Loop
```

Comment: The data I'm trying to extract is not exactly as what was shown in the example. No matching of students from similar schools? This is so weird.